# Android how to pass an object inside an object from Activitiy to fragment?

Tags: android

I have a requirement when I pass object inside an object from Activity to fragment created in viewpager. 
Below is my object class.

```
public class Questions{

    private int questionId;

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("Id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("DisplayText")
    @Expose
    private String displayText;

    @SerializedName("IsRequired")
    @Expose
    private boolean isRequired;

    @SerializedName("AnswerType")
    @Expose
    private String answerType;

    @SerializedName("Answers")
    @Expose
    @TypeConverters(AnswersTypeConverter.class)
    private List<Answers> answers;

    @SerializedName("Dependencies")
    @Expose
    @TypeConverters(DependenciesTypeConverter.class)
    private Dependencies dependencies;

}
```

it has two object inside dependencies and Answers. I have it in Activity. I'm fetching everything in database. I saw Parceble but it can pass Java primary variables not sure it will pass object inside the class.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could make your object (and any object in it) parcelable. However I recommend you to just pass your object ID to your fragment and make your fragment get the whole thing from your db.

Comment: An object can be made a Parcelable, or you just pass your JSON encoded element...